# Temp dir in java being overwritten

Tags: java, scala

I have a file that is in tar.gz format. I read it's path and then I try to write it inside a temp directory that I created. The directory gets over written as a file. What am I doing wrong? I am doing this in scala but using java classes underneath.

```
def restore(id: String) = {
    Future {
      val sourceDir = getSourceFile(id)
      val f = {
        new File(sourceDir)
      }
      if (!f.exists())
        throw ResourceNotFoundException(s"Failed")

      val tmpDir = Files.createTempDirectory("restoreMe")

      val p = Paths.get(s"${tmpDir.toAbsolutePath().toString}/")
      Files.copy(f.toPath, p, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this

```
Path src = f.toPath
Files.copy(src, p.resolve(src.getFileName()), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Comment: thanks, worked straight in first shot. Minor correction that you meant "src.getName())" is what I think